# xCode Is there a way to create a relation between back button and tabbar?

Tags: back, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I am a new bee to iPad development. I have created a Tabbar application in xcode and created 5 tabs. I am able to load 5 different views. Each view consists of a navigation bar cont and tabbar by default. I have added a back button to navigation bar to the four tabs. When in the detail pages i.e., Tab 2  I am tapping on the back button it returns to the Home page(First Tab View). and I go to other tabs and when I return to the 2nd tab home page is displayed. To my understanding when I am clicking on the back button a new layer is been created. if this so then how can I reload the view in the tabs when I revisit the tab

Can anybody let me know what could be the problem.

Thanks in advance,
Kris

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand your exact problem from your description, but reading between the lines it sounds like you've set the tab bar / view controller structure up wrong to me.  I have created a similar app in the past where I have a tabbar in the root view controller and then 3 navigation view controllers each assigned to a tab of the tab bar (but there's only one instance of the tab bar - reading your message it seems like you have one for each navigation view controller?)

Thinking about this more, if you are creating a new tab bar with each navigation view controller, then when you tap on another tab you are creating yet another view controller and before long you would have a massive number of view controllers and tab bars active.  You should only have one tab bar in your app.

If you have it set up correctly when you switch tabs you should return to whatever level of pushed view controllers you previously had within each tab.  Are you by any chance having to recreate the view controllers when the tab switch somehow?

Comment: I have created a UITabbar App using xCode4 and associated view controllers to each of the tab so I  am not creating a UITabbar manually. and in each View i have drill down of 2 levels and when I drill down to the second level and navigate to the othere tabs and come back to the same tab the second level page is displayed instead of the first. 

And I have created a Navigation bar with a Back button with the following code self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; With this i can navigate to the first Tab. but not to the first level in the tab. Sorry for creating any confusions.

Kris